# jQuery .ready() function use in other event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var Semester = $('#Semester').find(':selected').val();
    var StudentID = "<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>";
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_get_report_for_edit.php', 
        data: {Semester:Semester, StudentID:StudentID},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data['error'] == null)
            {
                if(data['no_result'] == null)
                {
                    $('#display').html(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    //error msg
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error: " + data['error'])
            }
        },
        error: function(ts)
        {
            alert("AJAX Error: \n" + ts.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

This function will run when the page load, but I would like to use this function in other event like `.click()`. Do I need to rewrite the function?

Comment: Yeah, you can wrap it inside a click function.. why not..

Comment: but if I put the function inside a click event, it will not run when the page load.

Comment: Just create the function with a name, and use it everywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the function with a name, and use it everywhere! Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function yourFunction(){
        var Semester = $('#Semester').find(':selected').val();
        var StudentID = "<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>";
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax_get_report_for_edit.php', 
                data: {Semester:Semester, StudentID:StudentID},
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data['error'] == null)
                    {
                        if(data['no_result'] == null)
                        {
                            $('#display').html(data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //error msg
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Error: " + data['error'])
                    }
                },
                error: function(ts)
                {
                    alert("AJAX Error: \n" + ts.responseText);
                }
            });
    }

    yourFunction();

    $('#element').click(function(){
        yourFunction();
    });

});
```

Comment: just my thoughts what is the difference of calling a function in a click event and putting the function inside click event itself?rather that the answer why ni just `$('#element').click(function(){ //hes code here instead of the function });`

Comment: i just wondering what is the difference between calling the function inside a click event and putting the code inside the click event?i hope i am clear now

Comment: No difference, but if you put the code inside the click event directly, you can't call that same function in another place without rewrite it, just that.

Comment: thank you for clarifying i was about to suggest that as answer maybe it wont because he needs to call that function again.

Answer (score 2):

name the function and call that function on your click event.

sample:

```
<button id='btn'> click me </button>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   foo();

   $("#btn").click(function(){
      foo();
   });

  function foo(){
      alert('data');
  }

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lrpe50p/)**

Answer (score 0):

> This function will run when the page load, but I would like to use
>   this function in other event like `.click()`.

Try using array of functions as parameter to `.ready()` , name first function in array , set named function to property of `this`:`document` within first array ; named function should be available at second function within array as property of `this`:`document`

```js
$(document).ready([
  function fn() {
    this.fn = fn;
    console.log(this)
  },
  function() {
    $("div").click(this.fn)
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create a function that will be called on your click event. Please see below example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#samplebutton").on("click",function(){
example();
 });

function example(){
alert("clicked");
}
 });
```